# How to code url that on load opens two tabs without user interaction required?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to code a url that when somebody visits, it automatically opens two new tabs with the urls I want.

so when somebody goes to http://www.myurl.com (just code here, no content), JQuery

two tabs(in the order that I choose) will be open for the user, for example:

1st) https://www.destinationurl1.com
2nd) https://www.destinationurl2.com

I have read some information and other questions where it seems that this kind of behaviour is often blocked(by Chrome mostly) unless the opening of the new tabs comes from a user's physical action, such as after a button click

I am looking at a way to acomplish this without any user interaction required other than going to http://www.myurl.com and without the user seeing anything other than the two new tabs opening.

Not sure if html, javascript, Ajax, PHP or a mix of any of these could be used.

Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: Basically, you can't ensure this functionality will ever work as expected. Browsers will block this "popups" evne if they are just tabs. The webpage has no control over the tabs. You could potentially write an extension for the major browsers that does that but that's the only feasible solution I can think of.

Comment: so just create the hidden buttons with `target='_blank'` and click them after load via jquery

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

The solution I found working (Though the user needs to disable popup-blocking on "smart" browsers) is by using
`window.open(document.getElementById('urlToClick').href);`

as used in here: http://jsfiddle.net/fLLrs/1171/

There's just about no JQuery remaining in the fiddle except the `jQuery(window).load(()=>{...})`

Once more to reiterate: It works **but the user needs to enable popups!**

### original

If you're using JQuery you could try it by using two elements like this on your page (no text so they don't render anything).

```
<a href='dest1' id='url1' target='_blank'></a>
<a href='dest2' id='url2' target='_blank'></a>
```

and then using

```
$("url1").click();
$("url2").click();
```

I've used this previously in some of my user scripts, though not in any which are supposed to automatically do stuff without user-interaction.

Comment: Most likely it'll get blocked by the browser automatically though, but in the end that's how it's supposed to be...

Comment: thank you @Campiotti can you tell me where would each of these two blocks go? I suppose the block with the two elements would go inside the <body></body> tags. What about the .click() calls? and would I enclose that between <script></script>?

Comment: The .click() calls would need to be called on the event listener of
`$(document).ready(/* call .click on the urls */)`
@dodecafonico

Comment: thank you @Campiotti . It's probably something obvious, but I cannot seem to make your suggested code do anything. It's in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j0cmL9fs/

Comment: It seems I had things a bit messed up,t should've been `$('elem').trigger('click');`
But never mind that as it seems to either be blocked or not working for some other reason.
I've updated my answer with the solution.

Comment: Typo here, $("url1") should be $("#url1"), the same for url2.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it simply ike below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.open(
      'https://www.destinationurl1.com/',
      '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
    );
    window.open(
      'https://www.destinationurl2.com/',
      '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
    );
});
```

Comment: thanks @Kunal Khatri I tried it but it does nothing. I enclosed this block between <script></script> and put it inside the body tags. Maybe that's not the proper way?